# issues with UIView animation swift 4 Xcode9

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to make an animation of a `UILabel` from off the screen to the center with a spring animation block. The first part of my code below in `viewDidLoad()` works perfectly, but when I add the animation block, it's like the code in the closure of the animation gets read first and it doesn't animate because the label is already in the place where I want the label to animate to. I have also tried to put this exact code in `viewDidAppear()` but the same thing happens.

```
@IBOutlet weak var follow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var followX: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.follow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.followX.constant = self.view.frame.width/2 + follow.frame.width/2
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.followX.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it (although I would try to move that animation to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`):

```
@IBOutlet weak var follow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var followX: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.follow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.followX.constant = self.view.frame.width/2 + follow.frame.width/2
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.followX.constant = 0
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}
```

To work with autolayout:

1. You first make sure the to begin animation is ready:

   ```
   self.followX.constant = self.view.frame.width/2 + follow.frame.width/2
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```
2. Then you change constraints to the final state of the animation:

   ```
   self.followX.constant = 0
   ```
3. Then you tell autolayout that the constraints were changed:

   ```
   self.view.setNeedsLayout()
   ```
4. And finally you call `UIView.animate` with `layoutIfNeeded()` to animate the change:

   ```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   })
   ```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much I have been struggling with animations for days!

Comment: @nicholasdmoore could you maybe leave an upvote too? :)

Comment: It says that the vote was cast and recorded but since I have less than 15 points or something it doesn’t show publicly

Comment: @nicholasdmoore Ok, dont worry bout it.. thanks anyway and good luck coding

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   if(once)
   {
      once = false
      self.follow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      self.followX.constant = self.view.frame.width/2 +   follow.frame.width/2
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }

}
```

and in viewDidAppear

```
 override func viewDidAppear() {

   self.followX.constant = 0
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  })

 }
```